# Quiero hacer un reproductor de musica en Android Studio pero no se como hacer para que se reproduzaca la musica seleccionada

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Cargo la musica por medio de este metodo

```
public void getSongList () {
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver ();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query (musicUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (musicCursor! = null && musicCursor.moveToFirst ()) {
        int titlecolumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex (MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idcolumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex (MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID); 
        int artiscolumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

        do {
            long thisid = musicCursor.getLong(idcolumn);
            String thistitle = musicCursor.getString(titlecolumn);
            String thisartis = musicCursor.getString(artiscolumn);
            listaarray.add(new Musicas(thisid, thistitle, thisartis));

        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }}
```

luego este método que me devuelve la listaarray cargada lo adapto a este adaptador

```
Adaptador adaptador final = Adaptador nuevo (este, listaarray); 
listamusica.setAdapter (adaptador);

// para luego llamar al SetOnItemClickListener y poder reproducir la música que selecciono pero no me funciona.

listamusica.setOnItemClickListener (nuevo AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
    @Override public void onItemClick (AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long pos) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer (); 
        Toast to = Toast.makeText (Main2Activity.this, " Has pulsado la posición: "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        to.show ();

        Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,pos);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), contentUri);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();


        }
    });
```

> Estoy trabajando con un dispositivo 6.0.1

Comment: El MediaPlayer esta declarado e instanciado dentro del click, por lo que no puede vivir fuera de ese scope. Usalo como una propiedad de la clase en la que estes. Asi su scope sera mas grande y permanecera existiendo mientras el fragment o activity que estas usando siga vivo.

Comment: Gracias Amigo ..ya voy a revisrevisar.

Comment: Nada Amigo . Es como si no obtiene el URI de la posición.

Comment: Es como si no obtiene el URI de la posición que da el setOnItemClicklistener  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No logras obtener la Uri porque estas haciendo:

```
Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,pos);
```

Donde le estas pasando `pos`, que es el indice de la lista, como si fuera el id de la uri. Lo que deberias hacer es utilizar ese indice para recuperar el objeto `Musicas` correspondiente a esa posicion en la lista.

No se como tenes declarada la lista pero la solucion deberia ser algo asi:

```
Musicas musica = listaarray.get(pos);
long musicaId = musica.thisid; //Aca tampoco estoy seguro como se llama la propiedad del id en tu modelo, pero debe ser algo similar.
Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,musicaId);
```

Comment: Gracias Bro .Cuando llegue a casa lo pruebo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Brother.. Funciono que chevere te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Que sigas cosechando Exito en tu  Vida.

Comment: Muchas gracias! recuerda siempre marcar la respuesta como correcta si te soluciono el problema.